# Error when requesting subscription to Microsoft Graph Subscripton for Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, .net-4.8

I run into this error when creating subscription for Teams from a .NET framework app. My endpoint responds with a validation token and the 200 status is received with the notification, but then I receive this error? need help

```
Exception while Creating Subscription: Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ExtensionError
Message: Invalid workloadResource
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2020-11-17T21:40:13
        request-id: 
        client-request-id: 
ClientRequestId: 

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Comment: Can you please share the request body?

Comment: share the request payload and the response log (request id, timestamp) for analysis